# KDB - Can't seem to import a csv file to a table

Tags: kdb

I'm trying to import a CSV file to a table in KDB.  I've done a bunch of web searching but can't seem to get it working.  Below is a screenshot of what I'm doing and what I'm seeing.  Thanks for the help.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to enter your file as a string and cast it to a symbol as it is trying to evaluate it when you just type it

```
q)`c:/q/files/Customers-6-24-18.csv
'18.cs
q)18.csv  //same error if just type 18.csv fails to evaluate anything more to the left of that 
'18.cs
q)`$"c:/q/files/Customers-6-24-18.csv"
`c:/q/files/Customers-6-24-18.csv
```

Answer (score 3):

You're getting an error with your file path. To get around it you need to convert the filepath to a symbol from a string. Also I think you need to have the filepath preceded by a semi colon, which the function `hsym` can do. Try the following code snippet to fix the issue.

```
hsym`$"<filepath>"
```

If you have issues with that try removing `hsym`.

Answer (score 2):

kdb can't interpret your file path because of the `-`s - it's seeing the rightmost part as `24 - 18.csv`

You need to cast a string filepath to a symbol, and use hsym:

`` hsym`$"c:/q/files/Customers-6-24-18.csv" ``